# Number of Unique IDs in Pivot table by month in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a table with

```
ID  | Target Date | Report Date  
11111 | 7/31/2017 | 6/16/2017  
22222 | 8/31/2017 | 6/16/2017  
11111 | 7/31/2017 | 6/9/2017  
22222 | 8/31/2017 | 6/9/2017   
11111 | 7/31/2017 | 5/9/2017  
22222 | 8/31/2017 | 5/9/2017  
11111 | 7/31/2017 | 5/2/2017  
22222 | 8/31/2017 | 5/2/2017
```

I am trying to show number of unique IDs due by target date for each month.

Result of Pivot table should be -

```
June (Report month)
7/31/2017  1 record
8/31/2017  1 record
May (Report month)
7/31/2017  1 record
8/31/2017  1 record
```

The same IDs may repeat in the weekly report but when we look at it over a month, it should count unique values. Excel 2013 has count distinct in the pivot but I am using 2010 version.

I tried to use the SUMPRODUCT and MATCH functions but did not get any result.

Comment: Basically, there may be duplicate entries as the entries come from reports every week. I wish the output to show only distinct results when put in the pivot table in Excel 2010 version which does not have the distinct feature

Comment: If the input included 11111 | 8/31/2017, then 8/31/2017 should show 2 records ( 22222 and 11111)

Comment: the reports come in each week, which will consists of same IDs and/or newly added IDs with the same/revised target date. I would like to know for the report month, I would like to obtain # of unique IDs due by target date.

Comment: so using the above example, 11111 appears every week, I wish to get 11111 | 1 (count) | 8/31/2017 (latest target date)

Answer (score -1):

In the Pivot Table fields, put [Report Date] in the ROWS quadrant and then put [Target Date] below it in the ROWS quadrant.

Then, put [ID] in the VALUES quadrant.  Once in the VALUES field, click the drop down arrow and select Value Field Settings.

In the Value Field Settings dialog box, select DISTINCTCOUNT on the "Summarize value field by" tab.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am working with 2010 version of excel at client site. I am aware about the Distinct Count feature but that is from 2013+ versions.